# Invoke web service on creating a web service proxy on data power

Tags: ibm-datapower

We have a SOA Service Registry with in our organization. This is a custom build web application. We ask different teams to register their developed services in the Service Registry. But we are not able to ensure that every team is registering all their services in the service registry. To enable better SOA governance, we want to enforce automatic service registration in the service repository by application teams, the idea is when ever they create a web service proxy on data power xg45 appliance, we want to invoke a web service call which will automatically create the service in the custom registry.

Our team is using IBM Data power xg45.

Is it possible to integrate IBM Data Power XG45 with the custom registry?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few management interfaces to DataPower. What you can do is to poll those interfaces on a regular basis to extract any info regarding deployed web service proxies. It's pretty easy to setup a web service call from whatever app have you. If you poll the management interface often, it's pretty much the same as if DP would have created the registry entry itself.

A good e-book (although a bit old) is: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4446.pdf

For instance, the AMP interface can query available WSGateway services in a domain called RIV. The response will include info about referenced WSDL files, service names and referenced HTTP protocol handlers. For some details, you may need to query further and for some details, you may be able to figure out what to enter into the registry from the export.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/appliance/management/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:GetReferencedObjectsRequest>
         <ns:Domain>RIV</ns:Domain>
         <ns:ObjectClass>WSGateway</ns:ObjectClass>
         <ns:ObjectName></ns:ObjectName>
      </ns:GetReferencedObjectsRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```